# How do I set up the cipher suites in java/eclipse for an http client?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

Our server has just had it's cipher suites restricted to:

SSLCipherSpec ALL TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

And now my test java client code fails with this message in the server log:

SSL Handshake Failed, No ciphers specified

and this stack trace on the client side:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:42)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:41)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.b(qc.java:485)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:381)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:453)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:625)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.startHandshake(qc.java:113)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:188)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:9)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:84)
```

Can anyone advise what I need to setup in my HttpURLConnection to get it to use these restricted cipher suites?  Or is this something I need to setup in the JVM arguments (in Eclipse)?

Many thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything. As long as the client supports that cipher suite the server will pick it. You don't have to restrict it at both ends. The server decides. It looks like your server isn't set up correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You're visibly using the IBM JSSE. According to [its documentation (see Customizing JSSE -> Customization)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/customization.html?lang=en)., this can be done by setting the `https.cipherSuites` system property:

> This contains a comma-separated list of cipher suite names specifying which cipher suites to enable for use on this `HttpsURLConnection`.

This is of course [exactly the same parameter as for the Sun/Oracle JSSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallationAndCustomization). (You might also find `https.protocols` useful, if you need to set the protocol too.)

If you want to achieve this on a per-connection basis, you can pass specific settings to your `HttpsURLConnection` using a custom `SSLSocketFactory`. Typically, you would implement your own `SSLSocketFactory` that delegates all calls to the default `SSLSocketFactory` (`SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()`), or an `SSLSocketFactory` coming from a custom `SSLContext`, but changes the `SSLSocket` created by any `createSocket(...)` method to change set its cipher suites. Something along these lines:

```
class MySSLSocketFactory {
     public Socket createSocket(...) {
         SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(...);
         s.setEnabledCipherSuites(...);
         return s;
     }
     ...
 }
```

Then:

```
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
HttpsURLConnection httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection;
httpsUrlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(new MySSLSocketFactory());
```

---

That said, the two cipher suites you're trying to use (`TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` and `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`) have only been supported in the [Oracle JRE since Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html), but they're already enabled by default there, so you shouldn't need any customisation.

The same table for the [IBM® SDK, Java™ Technology Edition, Version 8](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/ciphersuites.html?lang=en) only has columns up to version 7, and these cipher suites are not listed at all. I'm not sure whether this is just a part of the documentation that has not been updated, or whether the IBM JSSE does not support these cipher suites, even in version 8.

Comment: many thanks for this answer Bruno, I hope to be trying your suggestions out soon, and will update.